# How to store the status of an expr in alert rules to use that in annotations?

Tags: annotations, yaml, alert, prometheus, rules

I am setting up alerts for prometheus for whenever a node goes in "NotReady" my Kubernetes cluster. I get notified on Slack whenever that happens. The problem is I get notified with the same description "Node xxxx is in NotReady" even when it comes back up. I am trying to use a variable for the ready status of the node and use that in the annotations part.

I have tried using "vars" and "when" to assign it to a variable to use it in annotations.

```
  - name: NodeNotReady
    rules:
    - alert: K8SNodeNotReadyAlert
      expr: kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready",status="true"} == 0
      for: 3m
      vars:
      - ready_status: "Ready"
        when: kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready",status="true"} == 1
      - ready_status: "Not Ready"
        when: kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready",status="true"} == 0
      labels:
        severity: warning
      annotations:
        description: Node {{ $labels.node }} status is in {{ ready_status }}.
        summary: Node status {{ ready_status }} Alert!
```

I want to get these alerts : 
1. When node is NotReady: "Node prom-node status is in NotReady."
2. When node is Ready: "Node prom-node status is in NotReady."

Answer (score 0):

So the thing that you're looking for is over [here](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions). So you should end up with sth like this in description:

```
Node {{ $labels.node }} status is in {{ if eq $value 1 }} Ready {{ else }} Not Ready {{ end }} status.
```

Also worth to read [this](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_reference/) before making more alerts.

Comment: did not work for me, however this did : Node {{ $labels.node }} status is {{ $value | humanize | reReplaceAll "1" "Ready" | reReplaceAll "0" "Not Ready" }}.

Comment: But I am still not getting, the different slack alerts, for Ready and NotReady. Apparently the AlertManager is using the same annotations for both the Slack notifications. Any suggestions on that ?

Comment: It would be easier if I all value that you're getting in alertmanager because template as above should work. You're getting same annotation, but which of these two? Give me more details (as much as you can).

Comment: Thanks @Armatorix . I added multiple annotations for when the node is up and down. And called it in the alertmanager using 'if conditions'.